# List<User> returns null

Tags: apex, soql, visualforce, set

I have below code which compiles fine but UserTemp which is List returns null.

Can someone suggest what is the root cause? SOQLs are fine to return values.

**Code**

```
 get
        {   terrid = [select UserId, TerritoryID from Userterritory where UserID=: UserInfo.getUserId()].TerritoryID;
            ParentTerr = [select Parentterritoryid,ID from territory where ID=: terrid].Parentterritoryid;
            List<territory> territoryList= [select Parentterritoryid,ID from territory where ID=: ParentTerr ];
                if(territoryList!=null && !territoryList.isEmpty()){
                     PterrId = territoryList.get(0).Parentterritoryid;
                }

            List<userterritory> DMUser= [select UserId,territoryid from userterritory where territoryid =: ParentTerr];
              if(DMUser!=null && !DMUser.isEmpty()){
                     DM = DMUser.get(0).UserId;
                }
           // DM = [select UserId,territoryid from userterritory where territoryid =: ParentTerr ].UserId;
            if(PterrId!=null)
            RM = [select UserId,territoryid from userterritory where territoryid =: PTerrId ].UserId;
            Set<Id> UID = new Set <Id> ();
            UID.add(DM);
            UID.add(RM);
           UserTemp=[select Name , Id , Email from User where Id in : UID];


            UserEmail=[select email from user where id = :UserInfo.getUserId()].Email;

         //   UserTemp = [Select u.LastName, u.Id, u.FirstName, u.Email From User u limit 1];

            UserList = new List<SelectOption>();

            for(User temp : UserTemp)
            {
                UserList.add(new SelectOption(temp.Id, temp.Email));

            }
            return UserList;
```

Comment: SFDC Like Ravikant said check if your set contains value or not `UID`  use `system.debug('--------'+UID);`.. I think code looks good to me if you dont get any error. May be you need to rerender your page code.

Comment: Extreme sorry , my DI team has missed out the load. So SOQL returned no data. Sorry

Comment: SFDC Learner no need to say sorry. Good you solved your question..

Comment: I am assuming userterritory is a Junction object and how you are handling if there are multiple Users returned by the query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please apply `system.debug('###########'+UID);` before below line and check UID Is as a blank , I think UID is returning  blank value in your case.

```
 Set<Id> UID = new Set <Id> ();
 UID.add(DM);
 UID.add(RM);
 system.debug('###########'+UID); 

 UserTemp=[select Name , Id , Email from User where Id in : UID];
```

Comment: I think this would better go as comment

Comment: Cool looks like that is the cause. +1

Comment: Can anybody explain why my this answer is down voted?

Comment: I down voted it and should have explained why. Firstly UID can never be null as it is initialised a couple of lines before the query. (Perhaps the real issue is the values the set contains.) Secondly the query may return zero rows but will never return null so it would be worth clarifying that for the OP to help them become more self sufficient. And I also +1 that this would have been more appropriate as a comment.

Comment: Hi Keith C I have updated my answer, please take a look.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean by "blank"... Your answer has proved useful to several people so time to move on.